# DD4T 2.0 inprocess API unable to run locally

Tags: dd4t-2

We recently migrated to DD4T 2.0 In process API. The applications are running fine as long as we are using 2013 SP1 JARs.

When we replaced the 8.1.1 JARs the applications stopped working in local. 
We installed Java 8 and .Net Framework 4.5.2 in our development system.

Do we need any other configurations in order to run the DD4T application?

**To confirm**,

The Tridion core API works from local, while trying to get page content as shown below

```
PageContentFactory f = new PageContentFactory(); 
public CharacterData GetPageContent(int publicationId, int pageId)
```

We are getting below error at line number 1:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

My doubt is internally same error causing application to work locally

Comment: Isn't there a web8 specific in-process provider? Are you using that? http://dd4t.org/releases.html

Comment: Hi Nuno, Yes we are using In Process Provider and it works fine when deployed in server. Local application keep running and no errors.Thanks,Prasanna

Comment: To confirm Tridion core API works from local, while trying to get page content as shown below  1)PageContentFactory f = new PageContentFactory();  2)public CharacterData GetPageContent(int publicationId, int pageId) we are getting below error at line number 1 "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll", my doubt is internally same error causing application to work locally

Comment: Prasanna - I think the title is incorrect - should this be DD4T 2.0  in-process  API only runs on local?

Comment: Hi Dylan,For us DD4T application is failing to run in local when we used web 8.1 jar files